# OpenNI Zigfu - One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect, openni

I wanted to try the `Zigfu OpenNI` approach for my projects so I installed the following drivers.

1. `openni-win32-1.5.2.23-dev`
2. `SensorKinect091-Bin-Win32-v5.1.0.25`
3. `nite-win32-1.5.2.21-dev`

The samples `NISimpleViewer` and `NIUserTracker` are working well, but when I tried to test the sample scene `Blockman3rdPerson` from `Zigfu` I get this error.

```
// ERROR
One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

User: PrimeSense/XnVSkeletonGenerator/1.5.2.21: No license to use this module!
User: PrimeSense/XnVSkeletonGenerator/1.4.2.5: No license to use this module!
User: PrimeSense/XnVSkeletonGenerator/1.4.1.2: No license to use this module!
User: PrimeSense/XnVSkeletonGenerator/1.3.1.8: No license to use this module!
User: PrimeSense/XnVSkeletonGenerator/1.3.0.17: No license to use this module!

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
ZigInput:Awake()
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
ZigInput:get_Instance()
Zig:Awake() (at Assets/ZigFu/Scripts/Zig.cs:25)
```

I tried to uninstall and install my drivers and still got no luck with running the sample scene. Anyone knows where could I fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds to me like you haven't bought the required packages to be able to use Kinect with Unity.